# how update result of big query in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle

Can I update the result of query easily?

Assume I have big query which returns salary column and I need update salaries based on this query results.

**ID**- is primary key for my table

Now I,m doing it like this:

**STEP 1**

```
select id from mytable ...... where something
```

**STEP 2**

```
update mytable  set salary=1000 where id  in (select id from mytable ...... where something)
```

**Is there exists alternative to do that easily?**

Comment: Have you tried the second query?  It should be fine.

Comment: Yes, it is a fine query.

Comment: Yes it works but , I see that when the result appers in pl/sql deveoepr program, I can directly update the result on grid, and I think how it works in background?

Comment: I know it's possible also, but I think there must be clause something update result of query

Comment: @seyxsultan if ID is the pk for the table, then your update statement should just be `update mytable set salary = 1000 where <something>;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try `for update` and `current of`. You said that you are looking for something like "updating data on grid"

```
create table my_table( id number, a varchar2(10), b varchar2(10));

insert into my_table select level, 'a', 'b' from dual connect by level <=10;

select * from my_table;

declare  
  rec my_table%rowtype;
  cursor c_cursor is select * from my_table for update;
begin 
  open c_cursor;
  loop
    fetch c_cursor into rec;
      exit when c_cursor%notfound;
     if rec.id in (1,3,5) then 
      rec.a := rec.a||'x';
      rec.b := rec.b||'+';

      update my_table set row = rec where current of c_cursor;
     else 
       delete from my_table where current of c_cursor;
     end if;
  end loop;
 commit;
end; 


select * from my_table;
```

Comment: Why would you do this in a loop??

Comment: In this case i have to do this in loop. `Where current of` allows to update, or delete last the record that was last fetched by cursor. The cursror has to be `for update`.

Answer (score 0):

**Yes , you can directly update the result easily.**

**Here is example** :

```
update 
  (
     select salary from mytable ...... where something
  ) set salary=1000
```

Comment: Not really the same.

Comment: why you think that?

Comment: Consider (id,salary,v) values (1,100,a), (1,200,b), select id from ... where v = 'a' -> id = 1, both rows should be updated!

Comment: I think ID is unique, thats why he is using this column

Comment: @jarlh the OP says that ID is the pk for the table, though